# Like a Swiss watch

Tags: idioms, slang

Here in Spain we have a saying to mark that ***something works perfectly***,
we say that it works ***like a Swiss watch***. Is there any equivalent expression in English?

Comment: It all depends on what exactly you mean by *when something works perfectly fine*. Are you talking about a certain process proceeding smoothly or a mechanical device working the way it's supposed to be working? You really need to narrow down your requirement as there are a million expressions in English that could fit that description: **work out**, **go like clockwork**, **work like a charm**, **work like magic** etc. The list literally goes on.

Comment: Work like a well-oiled machine would work as well.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin It can be used in both cases that you mention, applied to a device or to a process. Using your examples, "go like clockwork" only applies if we are taking about a device? "Works like a charm" can be used with a laptop?

Comment: @RubioRic They're all "either/or" expressions, so to speak. Meaning, each of them is usually only used in one type of situation and not the other. Personally, I can't think of a phrase that's general enough to cover both of the situations that I described in my earlier comment.

Comment: On a side note, *works perfectly fine*, ironically, means something works "adequately," not "ideally." Simply *works perfectly* or *works fine* by itself are positive statements, but *perfectly* as a modifier for an adjective meaning "good" tends to undermine by overstatement. Someone who says *our marriage is perfectly fine!* or *my child is perfectly normal!* is being quite defensive.

Comment: "Like a Swiss watch" is perfectly acceptable in English too, and means the same thing.

Comment: @stangdon That is right. I daresay the Spanish is funciona como un reloj suizo, which is why I used **run smoothly** in my answer, which nobody, including the OP seems to want to acknowledge....oh well.

Comment: When I read the title I was expecting a question on the meaning of an *English* phrase "Like a Swiss watch". I would say that it translates well enough, though maybe not strictly common.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin I've accepted Marcus answer but I prefer your suggestion "works like a charm". I already knew that expression but I didn't made the match. Thank you!

Comment: @RubioRic Alright, I'll jump on the bandwagon and make it an answer.

Comment: Just to add a comment, in Serbian we also say "like a Swiss watch" :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like the expression [**to work like a charm**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/work+like+a+charm):

> If something works like a charm, it is very successful or effective.

Although the expression is general enough that it can be used in a lot of different situations, I probably would not use it to describe how well electronic or mechanical devices work. You can use it to talk about software, however. For example:

> That antivirus package that you recommended really fixed my computer. It helped me get rid of all the malware and adware that I had on it. **The thing really worked like a charm**.

Comment: This is a very reasonable suggestion that adds good insight to the issue, but I'm curious why the asker thought this best answered the question.  IMHO there are subtle differences between the two phrases.  To work like a swiss watch is a comment on the smooth and precise functionality of a machine.  To work like a charm is an expression referring to anything having a seemingly miraculous effect, regardless of how that effect is accomplished.

Comment: @DarrenRinger You have defined exactly what I was looking for in your second explanation. As I explained in the comments above, the main point is in "anything" not just a mechanical device. That's the reason for me to not accept the other answers. I was not looking for the exact translation nor the ones implying clocks

Comment: @RubioRic - So why did you ask for **an equivalent expression**? Your question is canon; comments are not.

Comment: @Myridium I don't get what you mean. I got a handful of answers and I have picked the one that I think that match more precisely what I was looking for. That is how these sites work

Comment: @RubioRic - that's not quite how it's supposed to work. Your question serves to help other people with the same question. Now other people will visit this Q&A looking for an **equivalent expression** to *works like a Swiss watch* and the answer you picked is not the most appropriate one. You need to edit your question to reflect what you're actually asking, not just append additional comments. Comments are not part of the Q&A canon, that is how all these stack exchange sites work.

Comment: @RubioRic - now if someone comes here genuinely looking for an **equivalent expression** without shifting the goal posts, they will not be able to, because people will flag their question as duplicate. Fortunately in this case there is an acceptable answer present, but if there wasn't, then that question becomes 'dead' territory, where no good answer can belong on this site, meaning you would have effectively destroyed the opportunity for someone to ask the question you are *only claiming to ask*.

Comment: @Myridium No, Community marks the most appropriate one upvoting. OP accepts the one that fits his needs best. People who come here can choose between the answers which one is the best in their opinion.

Comment: This is a well written answer but not the most relevant. Works like a charm just means works well, it completely missed the precise, well designed connotation.

Answer (score 32):

Yes, in English, you can say: x runs as smoothly as a Swiss watch.

This can be checked by googling to see sites where the expression occurs.

There are, of  course, many other expressions in English for this meaning.

Comment: Alas, to a younger person these day, this may be as puzzling as "You sound like a broken record." "What's a broken record?" Are any smartwatches coming out of Switzerland?

Comment: Good point @GreenGrassoHolm. XD To a spanish younger person it will be puzzling as well.

Comment: @RubioRic There are tons of expressions that live on despite technological change. Have you ever heard: It's time to hit the hay? That dates back around 300 years.....

Comment: @Lambie Right. The same applies to [avoiding something like the plague](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/364416/163363). I have never seen any cases of the plague ...

Comment: The image for saving a document still typically involves a 3.5 inch floppy disk.

Comment: @ChristopheS - I'm not old enough to remember it, but sliced bread must have been one helluva innovation.

Comment: Marcus's answer is a good one and thorough, but I have to give an upvote to this answer alone because it's the only one to mention the fact that "like a Swiss watch" is already a common phrase in English.  Yes, it does frequently cause young people in internet discussions to pause, but I've never seen it derail a conversation.

Comment: Please add a reference or a link to a website, it will make your answer all the better. I'm not doubting for a second that the answer is accurate but it lacks precision :)

Comment: @Adonalsium - my favourite is the icon for totally-digital voicemail on smartphones: an image of a reel-to-reel tape.

Comment: Here is just one example taken from GoogleBooks: [*Three hundred horsepower lay beneath that sleek hood, and it worked* ***as smoothly as a Swiss watch***](https://www.google.com/search?q=smoothly+%22as+a+Swiss+watch%22&num=20&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjk8YbDk6baAhWKKMAKHfWnDXk4UBD8BQgQKAE&biw=1309&bih=619)

Comment: Well, that's your choice. Personally, I find your suggestion to a non native speaker to check  the validity of your answer to be not very helpful or productive.

Comment: @Mari-LouA That's where I disagree with this site. Clichés are clichés, and some answers shouldn't have to be proved. Did you see the recent thing about "lips"? Where are sorts of nonsense is trotted out due to the mistakes in google image searches.

Answer (score 26):

In English, there are many ways to express that something works perfectly fine, here are some (these pertain to situations when something happens without any problems at all):

> **to go like clockwork** [verb phrase] - if something you have arranged such as an event or journey goes like clockwork, it happens in exactly the way that was planned, with no problems at all

- *After all that fuss, everything went like clockwork. You should have seen it.*
- *‘Everything go all right?’ ‘Like clockwork.’*
- *All through that summer, work on the farm went like clockwork.*

> **to go smoothly** [verb phrase] - if a planned event, journey, piece of work etc goes smoothly, there are no problems to spoil it

- *If all goes smoothly, elections are expected in May.*
- *In rehearsal, everything went smoothly, even the difficult fight scenes.*
- *My presentation went remarkably smoothly, until one student asked an awkward question right at the end.*

> **without a hitch** [adverb] - if a planned action or event happens without a hitch, it happens exactly as planned with no problems at all, even though some may have been expected

- *The first phase of the operation was completed without a hitch.*

> **to go according to plan** [verb phrase] - if something that has been carefully planned goes according to plan, it happens in exactly the way you planned it would

- *Development of our new computer system is going according to plan and it should be in operation by October.*

But, of course, you can put it in another way by using the following adverbial phrases. Be careful, they can only be used in a specific context:

> like a dream

and/or

> with no trouble

Comment: Variation on the first one: "run/ran like clockwork" instead of "go like clockwork"

Comment: "Like a well-oiled machine"

Comment: Please do not use code formatting for anything except actual computer code. Using it for highlighting or emphasis is a misuse of the feature, and can cause problems for alternative browsing technologies, such as screen readers for the blind, which have to handle code-text specially to ensure actual code is understood precisely. Reading letter-by-letter is not unheard of, for example. So please, avoid code formatting except when it is appropriate. Quote boxes, bold or italics, or whatever, can serve your purposes far better.